# "fi" turns into a capitalized Theta

Tags: texmaker

I am currently learning to use TexMaker and when I wrote "first" the fi turned into a capitalized Theta. Does anybody know how avoid this?

Comment: Do you know what font you're using?  TeX will turn `fi` into a single glyph, because it looks better when the two letters merge into each other.  It sounds like TeXMaker is misunderstanding the glyph in this font, and giving you Theta instead.  But I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Please post a MWE, with the packages and class you are using, then we can troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer though!